# Android testing Robolectric NullPointerException creating PendingIntent

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, robolectric

I'm trying to create a test of a method that clear some data in the database, cancel one existing AlarmManager (clearing the same PendingIntent) and deleting a file in the storage etc.

The test consist basically in three steps:
- Launch a method that create the alarms managers and put data into the database
- Launch the method that clear everything 
- All the check

The test is failing when Robolectric try to create the pending intent with a NullPointerException.

```
@Test
public void testClearExpiredVideoDownloadedContent() {

    mDatabase.post_action().addVideo(mVideoSample, StaticDbConfig.TableNames.DOWNLOADED_CONTENT);

    //Run the method to create the timer for downloaded content into the database
    int numberAlarmCreated = SuperBase.setUpContextExpireAlarm(mContext);
    assertEquals("Alarm has not been created", 1, numberAlarmCreated);

    //Run method to clear the expired content
    mDatabase.delete_action().clearExpiredVideoContent(mContext, mVideoSample);

    //ALL THE CHECKS
}
```

Method setUpContextExpireAlarm is crashing when i use the pending intent:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExpiredContentReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra(ExpiredContentReceiver.EXTRA_VIDEO_INFO, video);
            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, video.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(StaticAppConfig.MatDateFormat);
            Date d = format.parse(video.getExpiryDate());
            alarmMgr.setRepeating( //CRASHING HERE BECAUSE alarmIntent is null
                    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    d.getTime(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                    alarmIntent);
```

EDIT

This is the method that create the alarm manager and pending intent:

```
public static int setUpContextExpireAlarm(Context context){
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    ArrayList<VideosV0> videosV0s = new DatabaseHandler(context, null).get_action().getNotExpiredDownloadedContent();
    for(VideosV0 video : videosV0s){

        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExpiredContentReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra(ExpiredContentReceiver.EXTRA_VIDEO_INFO, video);
            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, video.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(StaticAppConfig.MatDateFormat);
            Date d = format.parse(video.getExpiryDate());
            alarmMgr.setRepeating(
                    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    d.getTime(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                    alarmIntent);
            Logging.i("Setting up the alarm for content ["+video.getTitle()+" ("+video.getId()+")], the alarm will be triggered on ["+video.getExpiryDate()+"("+d.getTime()+")] ");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return videosV0s.size();
}
```

Comment: if `alarmIntent` is `null`, this means there is no existing `PendingIntent`. Please post the code that you use to create the alarms in the first place.

Comment: I've added the method setUpContextExpireAlarm that set all the alarm.. i think is a problem of Robolectric because is fine during normal run on a device..

Comment: This call: `PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, video.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);` does not create  a `PendingIntent`. If you specify `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE` then no `PendingIntent` is created, it will only return one if there is already one there. Where is the code where you create the `PendingIntent` for the first time?

Comment: Is that one... that's why is not working maybe. So, the problem is that i need a different pending intent every time because i've got to pass different extra for each intent and i don't want to override it.. what do you advice to use?

Comment: You need to make sure that the `PendingIntent` is unique. Remove the flag`PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE` and make sure to use either a unique ACTION on each `Intent` OR a unique `requestCode` in the call to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`. This will ensure that it creates a new one every time.

Comment: If you write this into an answer i'll accept it okay? If you take a look when i create the PendingIntent, "video.getId()" as a requestCode, is think enough to have a unique pending intent? I'll use FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT

Comment: I need some flag that allow me to check against the cancellation of the PendingIntent. I mean that at some point i delete the pending intent (creating in the exact same way) and in the test i need to check is cancelled. Which flag do you think is better for me??? @DavidWasser Wasser

Comment: You can use the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE` to determine if the `PendingIntent` still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This call:

```
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
        video.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
```

does not create a `PendingIntent`. If you specify `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE` then no `PendingIntent` is created, it will only return one if there is already one there.

If you want to have multiple alarms, you need to make sure that the `PendingIntent` is unique. Remove the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE` and make sure to use either a unique ACTION on each `Intent` OR a unique `requestCode` in the call to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`. This will ensure that it creates a new one every time.